# Excel 2013: Is it possible to collapse rows only in a specific column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

In my spreadsheet, I'm trying to figure out a way to collapse rows in a specific column.

Right now, if I do Data -> Group -> Group... -> Rows, it'll collapse the entire row. I want to collapse rows only in a specific column.

Example:

```
|---------|----------|
|  hi     |  + data1 |
|---------|----------|
|  hello  |  + data2 |
|---------|----------|
|         |          |
|---------|----------|
|         |          |
```

And opening data 1 would turn into:

```
|---------|----------|
|  hi     | - data1  |
|---------|----------|
|  hello  | point1   |
|---------|----------|
|         | point2   |
|---------|----------|
|         | + data2  |
|---------|----------|
|         |          |
|---------|----------|
|         |          |
```

Is this possible to do in Excel?

Comment: No, not via the method you describe. However, you could hack it... You'd copy the elements you want into sheet B, then shift the cells up. Then, you'd restore them when you wanted to... It would be quite a bit of fiddling though, and all VBa

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. In Excel only whole rows or whole columns can be hidden or collapsed.